# DataTable Column value grouping and sorting

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datatable, grouping

`ColumnA` of DataTable contains 3 type of content:

1. Numeric
2. Alphanumeric
3. Alphabets

`ColumnB` of DataTable contains date format "**YYYYMMDD**".

I need data to be grouped based on 3 content types and then sort by date ascending order.

Example:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
A123457 | 20171114 
B246734 | 20171009
1234544 | 20170808
6789033 | 20171220
ABBCDEE | 20180102
A112233 | 20160202
1212122 | 20171115
NNNNNNN | 20171011
```

Grouping based on `ColumnA` Value and Sorting based on `ColumnB` value:

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
1234544 | 20170808
1212122 | 20171115
6789033 | 20171220

A112233 | 20160202
B246734 | 20171009
A123457 | 20171114

NNNNNNN | 20171011
ABBCDEE | 20180102
```

What we will be LINQ solution for this?

Comment: Do the answers here help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494342/c-sharp-doing-a-custom-sort-on-a-datatable

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith, thank you for pointing out but this requirement is bit different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is not the exact code, by the below way you can achieve the expected result.

```
//sort the date and put into same list
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                    myList.ForEach(i => { i.ColumnB = DateTime.ParseExact(i.ColumnB, "YYYYMMDD", provider);});

//check for regex match and add to list
                    mynumericlist = myList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.columnA, @"^\d$")).ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.ColumnB);
                    myalphalist = myList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.columnA, @"^[a-zA-Z]*$")).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.ColumnB);
                    myalpnumlist = myList.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.columnA, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.ColumnB);

                    //then combine all
```