# DataTable SortBy (Custom?)

Tags: c#, datatable

Please bear with me... I'm a database professional and this is what I normally do in the database when you need some quick custom sorting...

```
select *
from <table>
where columnname = 'something'
order by case column2 when 'c' then 1 when 'z' then 2 end
```

I'm trying to replicate that in C# using DataTables. Short of creating comparison functions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8699398/how-can-i-customize-the-sorting-of-a-datatable-column).. Is there a simpler/quicker/dirtier way to do this...

This is what I originally tried to do...

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Select("column1 = false","Column2 ASC, case Column3 when 'something' then 1 when 'somethingelse' then 2 else 3 end"))
```

Comment: Check this out:
[Sorting rows in a data table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107916/sorting-rows-in-a-data-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Linq-To-DataSet` to achieve the same:

```
var ordered = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              let col2 = row.Field<string>("column2")
              orderby  col2 == "something" ? 1 : col2 == "somethingElse" ? 2 : 3
              select row;
```

<strike>You can remember how it works in this way: the comparison returns a `bool` where `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`. If you want it to be at the end you either have to reverse the condition or (better) use `ascending` instead.</strike>  (related to the first version)

Now you can loop it with a `foreach`:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ordered)
{
    // ..
}
```

or create a collection with `ToList`/`ToArray` or more appropriate a `DataTable`:

```
DataTable orderedTable = ordered.CopyToDataTale();
```

Comment: I like Linq to DataSet approach, but I think there should be conditional ordering depending on value of "column2" field

Comment: Does Linq to DataSet require a database to run against? There's no database involved here... I parse a file and populate my DataTable. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: you're right, i have overlooked the multiple conditions. Edited my answer. @sam: no, a `DataTable` is just an in-memory collection. You don't need a database. Actually `Ling-To-DataSet` is a subset of `Linq-To-Objects`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter NO NEED... THANK YOU! I can kiss you. Worked perfectly... exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @samyi: in your original sql-query you have a `WHERE`. That exists also in LINQ, you just have to put following before the `let col2=...`: `where row.Field<string>("ColumnName")=="something"` (use the correct type if it's not `string`).