# C# (2.0) DataView filtering, how to handle special characters

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, dataview

I have an datatable ( _dataTableAvailable) that has the folowing values:

```
Name        Id   Selected
- Global    2100  False
ASpecial    1200  False
BSpecial    2300  False
GSpecial    400   False
```

After I used the folowwing code:

```
DataView dataViewAvailable = new DataView(_dataTableAvailable, "selected=False", "name", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

The sort order is changed!!

```
Name        Id   Selected
ASpecial    1200  False
BSpecial    2300  False
- Global    2100  False
GSpecial    400   False
```

What I want is that I get the same order.
How can I do this?

I use visual studio 2005 (C# 2.0).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems your datatable is ordered by Id ,So you may sort the dataview by Id and have the same results !
 for code example take a look at the following link :
[DataView.Sort - more than just asc/desc (need custom sort)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582374/dataview-sort-more-than-just-asc-desc-need-custom-sort)

Comment: That the id's where in this order is just a coincedence. It could also had been:                                                     Name        Id   Selected
- Global    2100 False
ASpecial    200  False
BSpecial    300  False
GSpecial    400  False

Comment: I justed checked, the _dataTableAvailable is also sorted by "name".

Comment: So ! sort your dataview by name !

Answer (score 0):

I found it. This is a bug and the only solution is to add an extra column and call this something like "NameSort". In here put the folowwing order.
So you get:

```
Name        Id   Selected NameSort
- Global    2100  False   0
ASpecial    1200  False   1
BSpecial    2300  False   2
GSpecial    400   False   3
```

Change the code to and it works fine:

```
DataView dataViewAvailable = new DataView(_dataTableAvailable, "selected=False", "NameSort", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```