# Sorting a DataView keeping the 0 values to the last

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dataview

I have the following values in my dataview dv :

```
  1,2,0,4,2,1,0,0
```

I would like to sort it in ascending order while keeping the 0 values to the last, something like this :

```
  1,1,2,2,4,0,0,0
```

I am currently doing this :

```
   DataSet ds = (DataSet)Session["test"];
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
   DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
   dv.Sort = "Value";
```

This gives me the following output :

```
 0,0,0,1,1,2,2,4
```

Is there a way I can get the 0 values to the last ?

I have also tried using the `dv.RowFilter` but that excludes the 0's completely. I would like to include 
the 0's. Is there a way I can do this ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582374/dataview-sort-more-than-just-asc-desc-need-custom-sort) might be usefull for you

Comment: Thanks Drasive ! I dont think I can accomplish what I am looking to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Linq-To-DataSet` which is also more powerful, less error-prone and more readable.

```
DataTable orderedTable = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(row => row.Field<int>("Value") == 0)
    .ThenBy(row => row.Field<int>("Value"))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

This works because `row.Field<int>("Value") == 0` returns a `bool` if the value is 0. `Enumerable.OrderBy` orders ascending(as opposed to `OrderByDescending`), since `true` can be understood as 1 and `false` as 0 all `Value=0` are coming last.