# Sorting a C1Flexgrid with datasource in own order

Tags: vb.net, sorting, componentone, c1flexgrid

I have a ComponentOne flexgrid (winforms) control with an (system.data.)datatTable as dataSource.

When the user clicks on the column header, I want that table sorted after this column with my own order. (one of the columns is a string column, where I want my own way of sorting)

I tried to override the sort functions of the flexgrid and use an own sort provider, but they are not called.

I think they sort within the datatable. Is there a way to tell the datatable how to order my column? Can I override the IComparer compare method of the defaultView or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When C1FlexGrid is data bound, sorting is governed by its data source. Refer this SO answer to do that

https://stackoverflow.com/a/582499/3331861

PS: Since this is a SO link, I can assume that it won't be deleted.