# Sort datatable based on value in the column

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable,

```
PId     PName   Qty
123     XYZ     2
223     ABC     4
434     PQR    33
```

I want to sort it on "PName" but not asc/ desc order,
If I pass PName as "PQR", then PQR should come first and then rest of the rows,
same if I pass "ABC" then "ABC" should come first and then rest of the rows.
Basically wants to reshuffle the rows where first row should be the "PName" which I am holding in a variable.

Thanks

Desired output
If I have "ABC", then the above datatable should reshuffle as,

```
PId     PName   Qty
223     ABC     4
123     XYZ     2
434     PQR    33
```

If I have "PQR", then the above datatable should reshuffle as,

```
PId     PName   Qty
434     PQR    33   
123     XYZ     2
223     ABC     4
```

Comment: Can you use linq?

Comment: yes. Can you please show me how it will work?

Comment: Refer my answer, as any clarification needed.

Comment: If you don't want to rebuild the table I suggest using a `DataView` and setting its `Sort` property to the appropriate expression based on a calculated column in your datatable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview(v=vs.110).aspx something like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/583943/491907

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("PId", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Rows.Add(123, "XYZ", 2);
    dt.Rows.Add(223, "ABC", 4);
    dt.Rows.Add(434, "PQR", 33);

    var stkLists = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
    var matchList = stkLists.Where(m => m["PName"].ToString().StartsWith("PQR")).ToList();
    var FinalList = matchList.Concat(stkLists.Except(matchList).ToList());
```

Comment: "Your complete table in list form", do I need to complete y datatable to list<T>?

Comment: Yes in list<T> form, This will give you desired output and will not sort entire table.

Comment: List<DataRow> stkLists = dtStk.AsEnumerable().ToList();
            var stkList = stkLists;
            var matchList = stkList.Where(m => m.PName.StartsWith(batchId)).ToList();
            var FinalList = matchList.Concat(stkList.Except(matchList).ToList());

Comment: m.PName shows DataRow doesnot contain a definition for "PName" and no extension method...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PId", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Qty", typeof(Int32));
dt.Rows.Add(123, "XYZ", 2);
dt.Rows.Add(223, "ABC", 4);
dt.Rows.Add(434, "PQR", 33);



string Name = "PQR";
DataTable newDt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r.ItemArray[1] == Name).CopyToDataTable();
dt = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r.ItemArray[1] != Name).CopyToDataTable();
newDt.Merge(dt);
```

Comment: James this will sort based on "PName" as asc/ desc. Please check the question