# C# datatable custom sort, one field first, then the rest

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, datacolumn

I have datatable which includes these values: [image]

Currently I'm sorting this way:

```
customTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Module asc";
```

I want to move the Intro be be the first module included and then by number starting from 1 the other modules, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you have any control over the structure of the datatable? If so, you could add an Expression field which is an IF() that looks for Intro and if it finds it, uses 0, otherwise uses the Module number. Then sort by that column.

Comment: I have complete control over the structure, what do you propose, can you please give me a code sample? Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataView.Sort - more than just asc/desc (need custom sort)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582374/dataview-sort-more-than-just-asc-desc-need-custom-sort)

Comment: Thanks @wdosanjos - in your posted link is a similar answer to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/583943/3485669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an Expression field on the DataTable, you can contain the sort within the DataTable itself (should you be passing it along to other consumers):

```
dt.Columns.Add("xxSort", 
               (123).GetType(), 
               "IIF([Module] = 'Intro', 0, Convert([Module], 'System.Int32'))");
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "xxSort ASC";
```