# How to sort custom classes in datatable cell in datagrid with autogenerate columns

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datatable, datagrid

I have `DataGrid` with `DataTable` `ItemSource`.
In  `DataTable` cells there are `myClass` objects with `displayField property` for display data and sorting.
Here I try to set correct `SortMemberPath` value:

```
private void profileStat_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
                e.Column.SortMemberPath =  "displayField";
                e.Column.CanUserSort = true;
        }
```

Now I am getting an error: 
`The type "" does not have a property named "displayField", therefore no sorting of the data family is possible. '`

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You should show us that `myClass` class code. Are you sure the field `displayField` is a property?
it should look like this:

```
public string displayField { get; set; }
```

Note that it must be public.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

```
private void DataGrid_Sorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
        {            
            DataView data = ((DataView)((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource).Table.ApplySort((r1, r2) =>{ //sort realization });

            ((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource = data;
        }
```

Thanks to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.sort?view=netframework-4.8
https://stackoverflow.com/a/582499/5261588